# How to get the length of a path using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have `List<Vector3D>` , where `Vector3D` is a coordinate.  `Vector3D` has method `double distance(Vector3D)` which returns the  distance between two positions.

I want to find sum of all distances between `Vector3D` elements of the list. I want to find it using Java 8 streams. I tried to use `reduce` but it can't help me.

For example, I have a list with (1,0,0) (2,0,0) (3,0,0). The length of this path should be 3.

If we are using Java 7 or lower we have to do:

```java
public static double calcPathLength(List<Vector3D> path){
    double length = 0d;
    for (int i=0; i< path.size()-1; i++){
        length += path.get(i).distance(path.get(i+1));
    }
    return length;
}
```

Comment: When I assume correctly, that you need a pair of vectors to calculate their distance, you may not use reduce directly, because it works on each element, but you could calculate a list of distances and then reduce this list to a single result.

Comment: how can i calculate a list of distances using java 8 streams?

Comment: Path between points `(1,0,0) (2,0,0) (3,0,0)` is straight line, so shouldn't its length be `2` not `3`?

Comment: I'm afraid streams are of no greater use here, because you would need a special stream providing you with two subsequent elements rather than the current element alone - so calculating the distances would be the same as < Java 8, the only difference would be the sum of distances if not summed up directly.

Comment: It would require a `Collector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation you are performing is called [Mutable reduction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction).

[Pshemo’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25263120/2711488) shows how you can implement such operation ad-hoc by providing the three necessary functions. However, when all three functions are implemented by a dedicated class it might be useful to implement these functions inside a class implementing [`Collector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) for easier reuse:

```
public class Distance implements Collector<Vector3D, Distance.Helper, Double> {

    public static final Distance COLLECTOR = new Distance();

    static final class Helper {
        private double sum = 0;
        private Vector3D first = null, previous = null;
    }
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
    public Supplier<Helper> supplier() {
        return Helper::new;
    }
    public BiConsumer<Helper, Vector3D> accumulator() {
        return (helper,vector3d)-> {
            if (helper.previous != null)
                helper.sum += vector3d.distance(helper.previous);
            else helper.first = vector3d;
            helper.previous = vector3d;
        };
    }
    public BinaryOperator<Helper> combiner() {
        return (h1,h2)-> {
            h2.sum += h1.sum;
            if(h1.previous!=null && h2.first!=null) {
                h2.sum += h1.previous.distance(h2.first);
                h2.first=h1.first;
            }
            return h2;
        };
    }
    public Function<Helper, Double> finisher() {
        return helper -> helper.sum;
    }
}
```

You will recognize the three function from the ad-hoc version. New is a fourth function, `finisher` which allows to specify how the final result can be extracted from the mutable container so we don’t need the `getSum()` call.

The use case simplifies to:

```
List<Vector3D> list;
//…
double distance=list.stream().collect(Distance.COLLECTOR);
```

Comment: You probably want a new collector each time instead of reusing same static instance.

Comment: @dkatzel: why? The collector is stateless; creating multiple instances makes no sense. Don’t confuse the `Collector` with the mutable `Helper` container which will be freshly instantiated for each mutable reduction, or even instantiated multiple times for a single parallel reduction. The collector shown here is thread-safe, mostly because the framework is designed to make it that easy.

Comment: The combiner doesn't do it's work well. It adds the distance of two sub-chains by measuring between the two subchain endpoints. In general, you can't expect sub-chains to be combined in-order, so the combiner and Helper class would be much much more complex to allow for this combining. The combiner isn't called anyway because the stream needs to be sequential, or the accumulator wouldn't do it's work well either.

Comment: @Mark Jeronimus: you are right regarding the end points but wrong regarding the order, as [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262580/how-to-get-length-of-path-using-java-8-streams/25265394?noredirect=1#comment39373583_25263120) for *ordered* streams, the combiner will be used in a way that retains the order, unless the `Collector` reports an [`UNORDERED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html#UNORDERED) characteristic.

Answer (score 2):

One of the options would be creating some helper class which would remember previously used vector and based on it calculate difference between it and current vector. This class could look like

```
class DistanceHelper {
    private double sum = 0;
    private Vector3D first = null;
    private Vector3D last = null;

    public void add(Vector3D vector3d) {
        if (first == null)
            first = vector3d;
        if (last != null)
            sum += vector3d.distance(last);
        last = vector3d;
    }

    public void combine(DistanceHelper otherHelper) {
        //add distance of path from current thread with distance of path
        //from other thread
        sum += otherHelper.sum;
        //also add distance between paths handled by separate threads like
        // when path of Thread1 is A->B and Thread2 is C->D then we need to 
        // include path from `B` to `C`
        if (this.last!=null && otherHelper.first!=null)
            sum += this.last.distance(otherHelper.first);
        this.last = otherHelper.last;
    }

    public double getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

and you can use it for example with `combine` instead of `reduce` like

```
double sum = list
        .stream()//or parallelStream()
        .collect(DistanceHelper::new, DistanceHelper::add,
                DistanceHelper::combine).getSum();
```

Comment: Why not let `DistanceHelper` implement [`Collector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html)? It would simplify the use case a lot.

Comment: @Holger You may be right, but I never actually implement this interface (I don't use Java 8 very often) and I am not very familiar with it, so feel free to post another answer with example of Collector implementation.

Comment: I noticed a small flaw: the `combine` method does not add the distance between two `DistanceHelper`s. If a `Stream` splits to two non-empty streams, the distance at the split position would be missing.

Comment: @Holger You are right, parallelism complicates things here. If we start building two paths from different points then we also need to include distance between end of first path and start of second path (like in case of points `A B C D` when we want to combine paths `A->B` and `C->D` we also need to include `B->C`). I am not sure in which order paths will be combined so I suspect that maybe we would end up with combining second path with first one so we using last point from first path and first point from last path will give us `A->D` which would be entirely wrong.

Comment: Safest option would be not involving parallelism, or somehow guarantee order of elements which will be `combine`d.

Comment: *ordered* streams will take care to accumulate and combine in the right order even when working in parallel and streams created by a `List` are ordered. For unordered streams the entire calculation makes no sense, regardless of being sequential or parallel.