# Calculate length of a path of coordinates using the Java stream API without an additional container class

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `List` of `Coordinate`s that each contain an x and y position. The class has a `distanceTo(Coordinate coord)` method, which returns the distance from the object's x/y position to that of `coord`.

Now I want to calculate the length of a path that is represented as `List<Coordinate> path` and I'm pretty sure that there must be a clever way to do this with streams. Probably via `reduce`, `collect` or `mapToDouble`... I tried to find a solution but was unable to. The best I could find was this similar problem: [How to get length of path using java 8 streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262580/how-to-get-length-of-path-using-java-8-streams)

But the answer there, to write a whole new class only for this one seems overkill for my use case.

Is there an elegant solution for this problem that doesn't involve creating a whole new class for distance?

Here is a simple code example of what I'm trying to do:

```java
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coordinate c1 = new Coordinate(0, 0);
        Coordinate c2 = new Coordinate(0, 1);
        Coordinate c3 = new Coordinate(1, 1);
        Coordinate c4 = new Coordinate(1, 2);

        List<Coordinate> path = List.of(c1, c2, c3, c4);

        // Primitive solution I use currently
        double pathLength = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < path.size() - 1; i++) {
            pathLength += path.get(i).distanceTo(path.get(i + 1));
        }

        // Using Steams
        

    }


    public static class Coordinate {
        private final int x;
        private final int y;

        public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public double distanceTo(Coordinate coord) {
            return Math.hypot(x - coord.x, y - coord.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: share the code and result of what you want

Comment: By “represented as List path”, do you mean “represented as a `List` of `Coordinate` objects”?

Comment: Yes. A List<Coordinate> named path. The formatting got lost when I posted the question.

Comment: @kerbermeister I added some example code. I hope it suffices.

Comment: Your solution is fine and readable. Not every problem lends itself to using streams. If you can't intuit the solution then don't try to force it. In every iteration, you're processing an element and it's following element. That's not one-by-one. It's doable with streams, but it will certainly be uglier than what you have already. Square peg, meet round hole.

Comment: @Michael I understand your point of view and I agree with it. But I'm a currently a student and when I see a problem like this (me not understanding how to solve this with streams) my curiosity takes over. It's the challenge that makes it intriguing for me.

Comment: I'm not sure someone answering the question "how do I willfully use the wrong tool for this job" is really doing you any favours.

Comment: Seems like while solving your task you're trying to apply some tool just to apply it. I guess it cannot be achieved ONLY with streams since by the nature of the stream you don't know the next element unless you read it. So, you'll need to somehow store the previous element to calculate the distance between previous and current.

Comment: @Michael I see it as expanding my toolkit. Maybe someday I have a use case for the stream approach. I don't see why its so bad to want to understand a subject/method even if it's not ideal for this very simple example. If streams are useless, why do they exist?

Comment: Nobody said they are useless. Trying to learn how to use them is okay. But I think this is a bad idea to use a tool anywhere. It should be used properly, where it is really needed or able to solve your problem better/performant/faster and etc.

Comment: "*If streams are useless, why do they exist?*" When did I ever say anything like that? They're useful. Not for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streams are very useful but not always appropriate for every situation - `for` loops may be far easier. However it is possible to do this calculation with a stream `reduce` operation without need for extra holder class of intermediate results:

```
double[] dist = new double[1];
path.stream().reduce((a,b) -> { dist[0] += a.distanceTo(b); return b; });
```

The accumulator function for this reduce adds each distance to the local array variable and is returning the second coordinate value `b`. That means the reduce gets called with each pairing of coordinates in the list sequence order, as mentioned by the [javadoc for reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)).

Obviously you cannot use stream `parallel()` here as the pairings passed to accumulator won't be in list sequence order.